# SVG clipPath with 2+ paths breaking in Chrome 38

Tags: svg, svg-filters

Unsure what's going on with my SVG icons since updating to the latest Chrome. They still appear to display correctly in Safari and Firefox the only other browsers that I am supporting. Was working perfectly in prior versions of Chrome I've been testing with.

Appears that there are two or more path elements inside the clipPath element in the examples where the icons are not rendering as expected. According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath I can place any number of allowed elements inside the clipPath so I believe that I am doing this right... so lost as to why it suddenly has broken down on me.

So basically if you look at the images you will see the kill cockroaches and the eye ball look different than expected on the left to how they are now rendering on the right hand side...

http://codepen.io/dapinitial/pen/Kflpv

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="diff-path">
      <path d="M17.19,7.349 C18.753,7.349 20.019,8.626 20.019,10.202 C20.019,11.777 18.752,13.056 17.19,13.056 C15.628,13.056 14.361,11.778 14.361,10.202 C14.361,8.625 15.627,7.349 17.19,7.349 L17.19,7.349 L17.19,7.349 Z" />
      <path d="M0.19,10.201 C0.19,10.201 6.833,20.152 17.19,20.152 C27.547,20.152 34.19,10.201 34.19,10.201 C34.19,10.201 27.414,0.249 17.19,0.249 C6.966,0.249 0.19,10.201 0.19,10.201 L0.19,10.201 Z M10.125,10.201 C10.125,6.269 13.288,3.082 17.19,3.082 C21.091,3.082 24.254,6.269 24.254,10.201 C24.254,14.132 21.091,17.32 17.19,17.32 C13.288,17.32 10.125,14.132 10.125,10.201 L10.125,10.201 Z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Filed http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=425113 for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a different "clip-rule" attribute for your clip-path. If I add `clip-rule="evenodd"` to your clip-path element it fixes things.

Comment: You touched my clip-path element?! How dare you!  Really though, you sir, are the best. How can I upvote you ?

Comment: Every time I see something weird in SVG, I read the spec again and realize how awesome (and complicated) graphics are...

Comment: True, I read the spec, but it says see *fill-rule* and then I have to head down the rabbit hole.  Thanks again mate!